# How to use aws-cognito to create resolvers for "login" and "signin" mutations

Tags: amazon-web-services, graph, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I have a `Graphql API` in `aws-appsync`, and I want to use the same path of said API to allow my users to log in and sign in using the `aws-cognito` service using `jwt`

Bellow a diagram of what I am trying to achieve

[image]

Is there any way to use `aws-cognito` in such way? how ? can you give me a quick brief on how to do what i am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible at this point. AppSync GraphQL endpoints are of the type:

```
<unique-id>.appsync-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/graphql
```

and these serve just the GraphQL requests.

Cognito operations (outside the OAuth flows) for signing, login etc are served from

```
cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

So both domains are amazonaws.com but different subdomains.

Comment: so I assume I need to deal with GQL and authentication in two different flows. Can you point me to any docs on how to use the Cognito API to get the JWT token. Basically i want to use AppSync with apollo react

Comment: You mean the Cognito docs? You could take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html

Comment: @Aaron_H I see, I did some digging, I can use Amplify just for the auth and still using apollo-js for graphql queries.